# Ripple effect animation not working in my HTML code

Tags: html, css

Here is code of my HTML and it is in body tag.
HTML code:

```
<div calss="wapper">
<div class="box">
  <span class="animate"></span>
    <div class="img-area">
      <img src="../picture/pic1.jpeg" alt="">
    </div>
    <h2>Abu Jafor</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut, sequi.</p>
    <p class="social">
      <i class="fa fa-youtube"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
    </p>

</div>
```

CSS code:

.animation is my animation class name. It's not effecting my HTML code.

```
.animate{
width: 5px;
height: 5px;
background: rgba(255, 255, 255,, 0.1);
display: inline-block;
border-radius: 100%;
animation: ripple 0.6s linear infinite;
}


@@keyframes ripple {

 0%{
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1),
              0 0 0 60px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1),
              0 0 0 120px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1),
              0 0 0 180px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
 }

100%{
box-shadow: 0 0 0 20 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1),
            0 0 0 120px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1),
            0 0 0 240px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1),
            0 0 0 360px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}

}
```

Can you please help me finding the problem?

Comment: You have double `@` in front of `keyframes` animation, should be `@keyframes`

Comment: You have multiple typos in your code. Double `@`, then `0 0 0 20` when it should be `0 0 0 20px`. Additionally `<div calss="wapper">` when it should be `class` and probably `wrapper`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try this,

**Edits**:

- `@@keyframes{...}` ripple change to `@keyframes ripple{...}` remove extra `@`
- `<div calss="wapper">` change spelling of **class**.
- Add `ease-in-out` to **smooth transitions**
- `alternate;` The animation is played **forwards first, then backwards**
- Add a background to body that is `body{background:#888;}` to know the **ripple effect.**

```
 animation: ripple 0.6s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
```

```css
.animate{
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255,, 0.1);
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 100%;
  animation: ripple 0.6s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}
body{
  background:#888;
}

@keyframes ripple {

 0%{
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1),
              0 0 0 60px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1),
              0 0 0 120px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1),
              0 0 0 180px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
 }

 100%{
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 20 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1),
              0 0 0 120px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1),
              0 0 0 240px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1),
              0 0 0 360px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
 }

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="wapper">
<div class="box">
  <span class="animate"></span>
    <div class="img-area">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/50x50/00ff00/fff&text=Logo" alt="">
    </div>
    <h2>Abu Jafor</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut, sequi.</p>
    <p class="social">
      <i class="fa fa-youtube"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
    </p>

</div>
</div>
```